# Do consumer-grade routers isolate traffic between machines?

Tags: networking, router, security

Hypothetically, we have a modern (2013-ish) consumer-grade router with three wired clients:  A, B, and C.  If clients A and B communicate using an insecure protocol (NFS, Samba, DLNA, etc), can client C eyeball that traffic if its NIC is in promiscuous mode?  Forgive me if "promiscuous mode" is not the right term for a wired network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Promiscuous mode only does this when all the devices are *attached* to a network hub, not a router or switch (a modern one, at least). You can see this for yourself by downloading [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and monitoring the activity.

When all clients are connected in WiFi, it's theoretically possible. But, I'm not sure if it's feasible.

Note: client C can easily see network traffic of A and B by other means (ie [ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing)).

Comment: Wireshark confirms what you suggested.  All I see is a periodic broadcast for the protocol in question.

Out of curiosity, are ARP spoofing attacks the only means of attack I should be concerned with, or is there a laundry list here?

Comment: @IncreasinglyParanoid yeah, ARP is likely all you will see (or other protocols related to routing).

Comment: You've really done a poor job of answering his question.  First... it depends largely on the kind of router.  Consumer-Grade can mean a lot of things to a lot of techs.  Home vs Business... would be a better question.  Home routers, typically do not offer much if any isolation.  Business routers can offer complete isolation even beyond layer-2 switching.  This is also true even for wireless networks that support AP isolation between the stations and AP/infrastructure.  It is even possible to make it impossible for two machines in the same broadcast domain to not see each other.

Comment: @TheCompWiz I think it would be more productive for you to write a new answer, than to criticize mine. If you have more useful information to offer the OP that is crucial to his/her question, people will up-vote your answer more (there is even a badge for getting a higher voted answer than the accepted one). Please don't, otherwise, waste your time rudely judging mine.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you cannot rely on it. Security comes from design and intention. Switches (and it's the router's built in switch that's doing this) accidentally provide traffic isolation as part of their bandwidth efficiency. However, because this is not by design, it can be trivially circumvented, for example, by overloading the switch's MAC table.

Think of it as a closed, but unlocked, door. You can't see inside just by looking, but nothing stops you from walking in if you want to.